# Python's Entry Widget

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I Am Inserting The Records In MySQL Table through the MySQL Python Connector.I am creating a project for a library.This is the code

```
var=StringVar()
fn=StringVar()
yn=StringVar()
ln=StringVar()
dn=StringVar()
an=StringVar()
kn=StringVar()
gn=StringVar()
mn=StringVar()
pn=StringVar()



photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("iplib.jpg"))
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("old.jpg"))
label15=Label(lib,image=img)
label15.place(x=0,y=0)
label10=Label(lib,image=photo)
label10.place(x=600,y=0)

def dynamic_data_entry():
    id1=ln.get()
    name1=fn.get()
    auth1=dn.get()
    doi1=an.get()
    dor1=gn.get()
    rname=kn.get()
    Address=pn.get
    reiss=mn.get()
    gen1=var.get()
    entry4.delete(0,END)
    entry5.delete(0,END)
    entry6.delete(0,END)
    entry7.delete(0,END)
    entry8.delete(0,END)
    entry9.delete(0,END)
    entry10.delete(0,END)
    entry11.delete(0,END)
    libcur.execute("INSERT INTO 
tcl(Book_id,Book_name,Author,DOI,DOR,Reissues,Recipients_Name,Address,Genre) 
VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(id1,name1,auth1,doi1,dor1,reiss,rname,Address,gen1))
    mydb.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo("INSERT STATUS","RECORD HAS BEEN ADDED SUCCESSFULLY")
    libcur.close()



def insert():
    top=Toplevel()
    top.geometry("500x500")
    top.title("INSERT RECORDS")
    label4=Label(top,text="Book Name:",fg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label4.place(x=65,y=70)
    entry4=Entry(top,textvariable=fn)
    entry4.place(x=270,y=75)
    label5=Label(top,text="Book Id:",fg="seagreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label5.place(x=65,y=30)
    entry5=Entry(top,textvariable=ln)
    entry5.place(x=270,y=35)
    label6=Label(top,text="Author:",fg="grey",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label6.place(x=65,y=100)
    entry6=Entry(top,textvariable=dn)
    entry6.place(x=270,y=105)
    label7=Label(top,text="Date of issuing:",fg="deepskyblue",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label7.place(x=65,y=130)
    entry7=Entry(top,textvariable=an)
    entry7.place(x=270,y=135)
    label8=Label(top,text="Date of return:",fg="gold",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label8.place(x=65,y=170)
    entry8=Entry(top,textvariable=gn)
    entry8.place(x=270,y=175)
    label9=Label(top,text="Re-issues(Yes/No):",fg="navy",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label9.place(x=65,y=200)
    entry9=Entry(top,textvariable=mn)
    entry9.place(x=270,y=205)
    list1= {"Adventure","Art","Children","Contemporary","Mystery","Cooking","Dystopian","Development","AutoBiography","Families","Fantasy","Fiction","Guide","Humor","History","Health","Motivational","Memoir","Novel","Paranormal","Personal","Romance","Travel"}





    droplist=OptionMenu(top, var,*list1)
    var.set("Select Genre")
    droplist.configure(width=15)
    droplist.place(x=265,y=290)
    label5=Label(top,text="Genre:",fg="lightcoral",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label5.place(x=65,y=295)
    label17=Label(top,text="Recipients Name:",fg="salmon",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label17.place(x=65,y=230)
    entry10=Entry(top,textvariable=kn)
    entry10.place(x=270,y=235)
    label18=Label(top,text="Address:",fg="midnightblue",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
    label18.place(x=65,y=260)
    entry11=Entry(top,textvariable=pn)
    entry11.place(x=270,y=265)
    button5=Button(top,text="INSERT 
    RECORD",width=12,fg="white",bg="forestgreen",command=dynamic_data_entry)
    button5.place(x=220,y=450)
```

However I get The following error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\sapna\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\sapna\Desktop\SAMARTH.py", line 70, in dynamic_data_entry
    entry4.delete(0,END)
    NameError: name 'entry4' is not defined
```

I am not able to understand what is the error.I have Also Imported The Entry Widget but even that is not resolving the issue.It would be very helpful if you could help me in resolving the issue
Thank You So Much

Comment: Read up on local vs global variables. `entry4` and the other entry widgets are all local variables.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined `entry4` before it was created

put the `insert()` before the other function and you should be fine

if you are not, feel free to comment on this answer

Comment: try using `global <all your entry vars>` in each function